# Why does a ADBannerView positioned at the bottom of the screen jumps to the top after exiting the full screen ad?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have added a ADBannerView to my view (in code) and positioned it at the bottom of the screen. Works fine.

However, after the user taps on the ad and it opens full screen, when they close it the banner then appears at the top. I can move it back down again in

```
- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

The problem is that the ad is briefly visible at the top before it then moves to the correct location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this as follows:

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{

    self.superView = banner.superview;
    [banner removeFromSuperview];
    [self.superView insertSubview:banner atIndex:0];


    return YES;
}


- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self positionBanner:banner];

    [banner removeFromSuperview];
    [self.superView addSubview:banner];

}
```

So basically, we remove the banner from its super view when the user taps the ad and then re-add back to its superview when the action finishes.